# understanding CUB ansi escape sequence

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape

i don't understand why sometimes the CUB sequence is allowed to continue through the previous line and sometimes not. the documentation tells it's not but in real situation...
http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#CUB

for exemple i have a screen filled with spaces on 80 columns and 24 lines.

i am at position line 3, column 4 which can be set with escape sequence : \033[3;4H

i move the cursor on the left 10 times with sequence \033[10D
wich will put me at position : line 2 column 76

so it worked ?!!
and sometimes it doesn't

please save me ! :)

I can reduce the situation but this is where i saw it :

I'm writing a vt* emulator and everithing works fine. i can launch emacs/vim and others but then i launched vttest in putty with the "script" command to record every typed characters and sequences. like so :

```
# script test
Script started, file is test
# vttest
...
```

when i do "cat test" in putty for exemple, it replays everythings like i did. when i play it with my emulator i am able to parse and to analyse every escape sequence they provide, but the display is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording on [VT100.net](http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#CUB) is fairly clear:

```
If an attempt is made to move the cursor to the left of the left margin,
the cursor stops at the left margin.
```

In a [recent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038426/vt100-escape-sequences-cursor-movement-wrap-around-to-end-of-line/28997266#28997266), someone pointed out that PuTTY honors a (non-VT100) capability `bw`, which quoting from ncurses' [terminfo](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual:

```
   auto_left_margin              bw         bw        cub1 wraps from col‐
                                                      umn 0 to last column
```

PuTTY's behavior for wrapping at the margins differs from VT100s, as you have seen.  ncurses has a terminal entry named "[putty](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty)", simply because PuTTY differs from all of the other terminals enough to make using a nuisance otherwise.

Comment: thank you for the answer. that explains things. another situation can appear when writing to the last column: if you are at column 80, and you write a printable charater the cursor should be at the new line and by writing another character this one will be on the next line (classic). But if you do a cub sequence it will be moved left on the first line without going down.